Replacement rule runs for a long time
I have a simple expression that reads (some expression in b) q^(8/3):
exp = (-((2 (1 + b^4) a[90])/(3 b^2)) - (8 (1 + b^4) a[91])/(3 b^2) + (
   5 (1 - 10 b^2 + b^4) a[92])/(24 b^2) + ((1 + b^4) a[93])/(
   12 b^2) - ((7 + 22 b^2 + 7 b^4) a[94])/(
   144 b^2) + ((2 + 11 b^2 + 2 b^4) a[95])/(
   1152 b^2) + ((2 - 61 b^2 + 2 b^4) a[96])/(2880 b^2) - (
   2 (1 + b^4) a[130])/(3 b^2) - (8 (1 + b^4) a[131])/(3 b^2) + (
   5 (9 - 8 b^2 - 10 b^4 - 8 b^6 + 9 b^8) a[132])/(
   24 b^4) + ((1 + b^4) a[133])/(
   12 b^2) - ((15 - 8 b^2 + 22 b^4 - 8 b^6 + 15 b^8) a[134])/(
   144 b^4) + ((3 - b^2 + 11 b^4 - b^6 + 3 b^8) a[135])/(
   1152 b^4) + ((3 - b^2 - 61 b^4 - b^6 + 3 b^8) a[136])/(
   2880 b^4) + ((1 + b^4) a[227])/(
   60 b^2) + ((79 + 4 b^2 + 79 b^4) a[228])/(
   360 b^2) - ((31 - 5 b^2 + 31 b^4) a[229])/(
   2880 b^2) + ((1 + b^4) a[237])/(
   60 b^2) + (1/90 (1 + 1/b^2 + b^2) + (5 (1 + b^8))/(24 b^4)) a[
     238] - ((30 + b^2 - 5 b^4 + b^6 + 30 b^8) a[239])/(
   2880 b^4) + ((62 - b^2 + 62 b^4) a[253])/(
   7560 b^2) + ((63 - b^2 - b^4 - b^6 + 63 b^8) a[254])/(
   7560 b^4)) q^(8/3)

Then I put in a replacement rule /. {x_ q^n_ + y_ :> {x, y}} that should do nothing, which runs for a very long time,
exp /. {x_ q^n_ + y_ :> {x, y}} // Timing

(* returns {18.2696, ... } *)

The replacement rule should do nothing, since
MatchQ[exp, x_ q^n_ + y_] (* returns False *)


I wonder what is Mathematica doing behind the scene?

No idea, but on my computer it takes 0.000124 and I do have a low end laptop.

This also runs immediately for me.  Consider restarting the kernel and trying again.

28 seconds for me, then 29 with a fresh kernel.

@march, yes I tried restarting the kernel, but still the same 18s. I am running on Mathematica 13.3 on a MacOS Monterey.

You can reproduce the issue with a bit cleaner example: Sum[a[i]/b[i], {i, 20}] q^2 /. {x_ q^n_ + y_ :> {x, y}}. And as explained by @DanielLichtblau in the question I linked, the problem occurs because Plus is both Flat and Orderless, which you can again see with Attributes[f] = {Flat, Orderless}; (f @@ Table[a[i]/b[i], {i, 20}] q^2) /. {f[x_ q^n_, y_] :> {x, y}}.
